# How to create elements, set attribute, use innerHTML, and appendChild with JS and DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom, innerhtml, appendchild

I am writing a sample program in HTML/JS to demonstrate creating an array of user-defined objects (property/value), creating an element, adding data from the object array using innerHTML, and then appending the newly filled element to print it using appendChild();

For some reason, running the program provides no output besides what I hard-code as debugging. View source is also not very helpful given the language.

Please forgive me for the simple question, I am new to JS and have spent many hours reading many resources - I feel I am probably missing something small.

Thank you!!

```
<title>
This is my title.
</title>

<body>
<p>xXx<br/></p>
<script>

var array = new Array();

var thing1 = {
property: "value-1"
};

        var thing2 = {
        property: "value-2"
        };


        array.push(thing1);
        array.push(thing2);

        for (index = 0; index < array.length; ++index) {

            test_el = document.createElement("p");

            test_el.innerHTML(array[index].property);

            document.body.appendChild(test_el);

        };
        //I wish to print 'value' text into the body from my object, that is all

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Your variable is `test_el`, but you're appending `text_el`. I imagine that would throw an error in console though?

Comment: Ah - thanks! Good eye. Unfortunately - I still get a blank screen after fixing. This should be pretty simple to run, no?

Comment: Have you looked at your console? You have an error: *"Uncaught TypeError: test_el.innerHTML is not a function"*.  You change an element's HTML by doing `.innerHTML = ...`, not `innerHTML( ... )`.

Comment: I did not know I could do that!
Got it working. I LOVE YOU MAN.

Comment: Console is your best friend! Press `F12` while on your page to see it (or `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `J` in Chrome). You can use `console.log(test_el)`, for example, if you ever want to track the value of something.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your error seems to be with `innerHTML`, that is not a function, so you should put that value equal to something. I have corrected your code so you can see the result.

```js
var array = new Array();
var thing1 = {
  property: "value-1"
};
var thing2 = {
  property: "value-2"
};

array.push(thing1);
array.push(thing2);

for (index = 0; index < array.length; ++index) {
  test_el = document.createElement('p');

  test_el.innerHTML = array[index].property;

  document.body.appendChild(test_el);
};
```

```html
<title>
  This is my title.
</title>

<body>
  <p>xXx<br/></p>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes this, as well as Tyler Roper's response, helped a whole bunch in figuring out my real world program. Thank you!